# iOS potential leak of an objects property

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm switching from ARC to MRC now because I take an old project. However I'm not familiar with MRC, now when I analyse my code , there is a potential leak of an objects property.

here is the code

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AnotherObject *anotherObject;
- (id)init{
    ...
    _string = [[NSSting alloc] init];
    ...
}

- (void)doThings{
    self.anotherObject.text = self.string; // text is also a retain property of anotherObject,and anotherObject is also a property
}

- (void)dealloc{
   [_string release];
   [_anotherObject release];
   ...
}
```

I try to fix it , so I make `_string` an autorelease object

```
- (id)init{
    ...
    _string = [[[NSSting alloc] init]autorelease];
    ...
}
```

and still release `_string` in the `dealloc` method, It works and when I analyze my code again ,the potential leak disappeared.

But I can't figure out why, could someone explain it for me？？ thank you very much.

Comment: The usual pattern would be `_string = [[NSString alloc] init]` in your init method (I'm assuming that's just an example since normally you wouldn't just make an empty string like that).  Then `[_string dealloc]` in your `dealloc` method.  Just like you had it.  Is `anotherObject` being deallocated, and does `anotherObject` properly release its `text` property in `dealloc`?

Comment: yes, the `text` property is also released in `dealloc`@AaronGolden

Comment: and I forgot to mention that `anotherObject` is also a retain property of `self`

Comment: Perhaps `anotherObject` is leaking and taking the string with it.  If you set a break point in `anotherObject`'s dealloc method, do you hit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initialize method you are allocating your string. So it means your variable is the owner of the object. But when its work has been completed still it is retaining the object. So in that case you are getting potential leak warning.

But after you put autorelease, So it is releasing the object when work has been completed. So your potential leak has been disappeared.

Autorelease just removes a retain count from the object it does not "free" the memory immediately like in c. When the autorelease pool ends all auto released objects with a count of 0 will have their memory freed up.

Comment: If you assign the ivar directly with auto release then it will have a retain count of zero after the next auto release pool pop.  It's very unlikely that that is what you want for an ivar that you're releasing in dealloc.  If you call doThings in a later turn of the run loop than your init method, _string is likely to have been deallocated by the time you assign it to anotherObject.text.

Answer (score 0):

The correct pattern is the one you originally tried.  Assign your ivar without an autorelease in `init`, like:

```
_string = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

and release it in `dealloc` like:

```
[_string release];
```

If you use the property's setter you need to use autorelease, because the property (being declared with `retain`) will retain the object you assign to it.  So if you assign your string property with `self.string = ...` then it should look like:

```
self.string = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
```

In your question you said that the static analyzer picked up the error.  If you look at the static analyzer messages in the issues tab in Xcode, you can actually expand the analysis issue and Xcode will show you the code paths the analyzer took to see the potential leak.  That can really help with tracking down these sorts of issues.
[image]